# Не отображается интерфейс и терминал в Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, dual-boot

Установил Ubuntu 16.04 LTS рядом с Windows 10. Когда захожу в Ubuntu вижу строку ввода пароля и при его вводе, вижу только заставку рабочего стола и курсор мыши. При попытке открыть терминал <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ATL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> или <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> мышка пропадает но ничего не отображается. Читал, что это может быть связанно с видеокартой Nvidia, что стоит у меня. Для того чтобы переустановить драйвера видеокарты или чтобы переустановить графический интерфейс Ubuntu нужен же терминал.
Что я могу сделать в такой ситуации?
Только начал использовать Ubuntu, буду рад любой подсказке.

Comment: Как правило с Nvidia в linux-системах меньше проблем, чем с тем же Radeon. Моя карта (тоже Nvidia и тоже на Ubuntu, только 18.04), все подтянула автоматом, все работает идеально. Есть вероятность, что система установлена не совсем корректно.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + F2, например, пробовали?

Comment: чистая логика: раз вы задаёте вопрос, ожидая ответа, значит от попыток самостоятельно решить задачу **уже** отказались. единственно возможное в таком случае решение: установить систему заново. p.s. если система нужна для работы, а не для исследований/развлечений, **ни в коем случае** не устанавливайте никаких там «драйверов» или тому подобных **левых** программ.